Is there a standard name for a convex set whose (algebraic) relative interior is non-empty?
I am writing a document in which I will have to use extensively convex sets whose (algebraic) relative interiors are non-empty. I am wondering if there is a standard name for such sets, the name that would come to mind for me would be a full convex set or fully convex set. This is because such a set contains its interior.
Formally, if $E$ is a vector space and $C$ a convex set, then $\operatorname{ri} C=\{ x\in C: \operatorname{cone} (C-x)=\operatorname{span}(C-x)\}$ is the algebraic relative interior of $C$.
In case $E$ is a TVS, the relative interior of some $C$ is the interior with respect to the relative topology of $C$.
I feel like if a convex set with non empty relative interior was said to be "X" then a convex set with non empty algebraic relative interior should be called "algebraically X" or similar. I was suggesting that full was a nice insight but maybe the term already exists.

Could you please provide a definition of what you mean by an algebraic relative interior? Is that also known as the core of the set? (i.e., if operating in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\textrm{core} C = {x\in C,|,\textrm{cone}(C-x)=\mathbb{R}^n}$)

@Zim Thanks for the reply, the algebraic relative interior that I use is a bit different but the spirit is similar so an answer for the core would probably give an answer for the algebraic relative interior.

Thanks for the clarification! Okay, cool, I just know this as the "relative interior". I don't know of a specific name for sets with this property, but it should be noted that relative interior of a convex set is always nonempty for finite dimensional spaces (Fact 6.14, Bauschke/Combettes' book, 2nd edition). If your space could be infinite dimensional though, I agree it would be nice to have some good terminology for this property.

@Zim yes, exactly the definition I use comes from this book (which is a very nice one). I am indeed more interested in infinite dimensional spaces, the finite dimensional case is typically much easier.
